# What do you call the sound of a bell?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

If you wanted to describe the sound of a small brass bell that you can hold in your hand ([this is an example image of what I mean](http://photo-dict.faqs.org/photofiles/list/963/3963bell.jpg) - what word would you use? *Brrring*? *Bling*?

Comment: what about jingle or ting?

Comment: I believe [Poe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bells) has all the bell sounds pretty much covered. In order of size, his bells *jingle, tinkle, chime, ring, clang, knell, toll,* and more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term should be [tinkle](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/tinkle_2). For example:

> - *A bell tinkled as the door opened.*
> - *The maid tinkled a bell.*

Comment: @Patrick: Sorry, I changed it, I think this one is more appropriate. :)

Comment: Not to be sorry, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Only the smallest bells tinkle. A good example is the bell that signals someone entering a shop.  A hand bell of the size pictured makes quite a loud noise, and *ring* would be more appropriate, but maybe the OP's picture is not what was really intended.

Comment: @z7sgѪ I have checked two dictionaries but none of them discriminates. What did you mean by *"but maybe the OP's picture is not what was really intended"*? I didn't get it. :)

Comment: tinkle: *a light high ringing sound* I just didn't think the picture looked like a "tinkly" bell.  It's hard to tell though.  You wouldn't say this guy's bell tinkles for example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Town_crier_Peter_Moore.JPG/272px-Town_crier_Peter_Moore.JPG

Comment: @z7sgѪ Now you've made me laugh! I was thinking of suggesting "tintinnabulation" (which I misspelled), but that guy's bell isn't of the tintinn... variety any more than it is "tinkly".

Comment: In my region (Canada) 'tinkle' is slang for 'urinate.' In context it would still mean the sound of a small bell, but listeners would not be able to help making the urination connection.

Comment: For t@JAMs reasoning, it is probably better to say "the bell tinkled" than "the person tinkled the bell".

Answer (score 6):

Edgar Allen Poe's poem *The Bells* pretty much covers this. In this poem:

> sleigh bells *tinkle* and *jingle*,
>   wedding bells *ring* and *chime*,
>   alarm bells *clang*,
>   funeral bells *toll* and *knell*.

For small bells, I think *tinkle, jingle, ring* would all apply.

Answer (score 5):

The sound of a hand held brass bell, to me, is "**ding-a-ling**."

"Tinkle" would apply at best to a very small bell (and at worst is slang for urinate as I commented above), and "brrring" would apply to the repeated hammering on a bell such as one used to hear telephones or school bells make. "[Bling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bling?s=t&ld=1031)" is slang for gaudy jewellery!

Answer (score 4):

The sound of a small brass bell is a ‘tintinnabulation’.